# Finding $ \lbrace a_{n}\rbrace $ s.t. $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }a_{n}=1$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }a_{n}^{n}=2015$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

The following problem appears in our analysis assignment.

> Find a sequence $ \lbrace a_{n}\rbrace $ of real numbers such that $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }a_{n}=1\text{ and }\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }a_{n}^{n}=2015.$$

Could anyone give me some help to find such a sequence ?

Any hints/ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Cosider $a_n=2015^{1/n}$.

Comment: @tetori Oh its work! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a_n = 1+\frac{\log(2015)}{n} $$
deserves a try.